# Rust: `self` has an anonymous lifetime `'_` but it needs to satisfy a `'static` lifetime requirement

Tags: multithreading, rust, thread-safety, automatic-ref-counting

I read the official Rust book, in particular the Fearless Concurrency chapter. I understand why this code does not compile. What I need is a some guidance how to fix it.

```
impl Maze {
    fn solve (&self, points: String) -> Path {
        ...

        use std::thread::{spawn, JoinHandle};
        use std::sync::mpsc::channel;
        use std::sync::Arc;

        let mut mazearc = Arc::<&Maze>::new(&self);

        let mut threads = Vec::<JoinHandle<_>>::with_capacity(128);
        let (tx,rx) = channel();

        for i in 0..path.len() {
            let txcopy = tx.clone();
            let segcopy = path[i].clone();
            let sharedmaze = mazearc.clone();
            threads.push(spawn(move || {
                let partialpath = sharedmaze.solve_segment(segcopy);
                txcopy.send((i, partialpath));
            }));
        }

        for h in threads.into_iter() {
            h.join();
        }

        let mut pp: Vec::<(usize,Vec::<Point>)> = rx.iter().collect();
        pp.sort_by_key(|s| s.0);

        for i in 0..path.len() {
            path[i].nodes = pp[i].1.clone();
        }

        return Path::join(path, &self);
    }
}
```

Produces a compile time error:

```
error[E0759]: `self` has an anonymous lifetime `'_` but it needs to satisfy a `'static` lifetime requirement
   --> temp.rs:228:21
    |
200 |     fn solve (&self, points: String) -> Path {
    |               ----- this data with an anonymous lifetime `'_`...
...
228 |         let mut mazearc = Arc::<&Maze>::new(&self);
    |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ----- ...is captured here...
...
237 |             threads.push(spawn(move || {
    |                          ----- ...and is required to live as long as `'static` here
```

I am disallowed from importing crates, so this has to be done with std threads.

Comment: `Arc<&Maze>` is not very useful, you need `Arc<Maze>` to satisfy the `'static` lifetime requirement. To achieve that, you'd need `solve` to consume `self`, i.e. accept `self` rather than `&self` (and possibly return `self` at the end to the caller). A much simpler way of achieving your goal is to use [scoped threads](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/0.8.0/crossbeam/fn.scope.html) from the excellent and near-standard [crossbeam crate](https://crates.io/crates/crossbeam).

Comment: I did as you suggested. Now the program does not terminate at all. It just sits there quitely, not allocating, not computing. Just idle.

Comment: Solved it. The transmitters did go out of scope but did not close somehow. The channel receiver was waiting indefinately after consuming all supposed data.

Comment: If you have a working solution, you can post an answer, so that the question doesn't remain open.